# Withdraw function of the DAO stuck in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, parity, the-dao, thedao-refund

so I am finally trying to refund my DAO tokens for ETH.

MyEtherWallet (downloaded from https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/tag/v3.3.7) didn't work for me (it did not load the ETH amount I should receive for some reason), so I tried following the instructions on: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds#How_Do_I_Withdraw_The_DAO_ETH_Refund_Using_Go_Ethereum.3F.

I wanted to use geth JavaScript Console (synced using Parity) and retrieve my ETH.
I was able to call the approve function just fine, as you can see here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9fe0959ac26fb54f1b80001f2ea7f83c2444e04fa185aef4785e0f9d8e277dc6.

However, when I got to the withdrawal contract, it got stuck:

[image]

I don't know what else to do. Can someone help me? The account address is 0x7Aed845a443E120030A0d6dCf5BBad1b57c4588B.

Thank you :)